# nginx forward https traffic on windows

Tags: ssl, nginx, windows-server-2016

Let's say I have two webservers running on `https://server:10000` and `https://server:10001`, that is, SSL termination happens on my server, not on nginx.

I want nginx to route `https://server0.mydomain.com` to `server:10000` and  `https://server1.mydomain.com` to `server:10001`

I came up with the following, but how can I match based on hostname?

```
stream {
    upstream server0 {
        server server:10000;
    }

    server {
        listen 443;
        proxy_pass server0;
    }
}
```

This doesn't work because, I think, nginx wants to terminate ssl connection, instead of just passing the traffic through?

```
http {
    upstream server0 {
        server localhost:19080;
    }

    server {
        listen 443;

        location / {
            proxy_pass https://server0;
        }
    }
}
```

I saw this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/40135151/3515174 but ssl_preread doesn't appear to work on windows.

What are my options?

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html

Comment: It's not a production server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recompiled nginx with `--with-stream_ssl_preread_module` and followed this guide  https://stackoverflow.com/a/40135151/3515174