# Reverse proxy OpenVpn using Haproxy or Nginx

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, haproxy, openvpn

i was wondering how it is possible to reverse proxying an openvpn connection using the SNI, i've read so much about that: [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34741571/nginx-tcp-forwarding-based-on-hostname/40135151) and [HERE](https://serverfault.com/questions/625362/can-a-reverse-proxy-use-sni-with-ssl-pass-through/952499#952499)

I've tried any kind of solution, using haproxy and using nginx, but it seems that my client (i've tried Tunnelblick and a simple openvpn client on linux) does not send the SNI information

Basically, this is the result that i want to achieve:

```
vpn1.app.com ─┬─► *.app.com dns -> nginx at my public ip ─┬─► vpn1 at 10.0.0.3

vpn2.app.com ─┤                                           ├─► vpn2 at 10.0.0.4

vpn3.app.com ─┘                                           └─► vpn3 at 10.0.0.5
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I would suggest asking questions that are similar to this one on [sf].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[UPDATE]** I've searched for all these days and looked around for a solution, but, in conclusion, it seems that OpenVpn, in it's architecture, isn't sending around to the server the SNI indication, so, no chance to do that.

I'll use the classic old-school way: NAT and a proper public dns to manage them.

Answer (score 0):

So it's 2023 and OpenVPN 2 still doesn't let you send SNI in their TLS packets.

If you switch to OpenVPN 3, tho, you can!

In Windows you need to compile the client by yourself.

After that you can add the "sni" option to your client-side config file and use it through the terminal client you just compiled.

For example:

```
...
remote test.com 1194
sni "test.com"
...
```

Still, personally, I was not able to reverse proxy the TCP stream using nginx and $ssl_preread_server_name like some guides suggested to.

Link to compile openvpn3 client for Windows, Linux and macOs:

https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn3

Comment: I can't find any documentation on the `sni` feature. [this](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/ticket/1404) claims it's not possible anyways. I also tried, but trying to log the SNI value with nginx reveals that nginx can't see anything.