# Nginx `stream` for multiple type of traffic

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy

Is there a way to use the Nginx `stream` block for multiple types of traffic going to the same upstream server?

### This works

```
http {
  map $http_host $upstream {
    example.com 1100;
    www.example.com 1100;
  }
  upstream 1100 {
    server 127.0.0.1:1100;
  }
  server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://$upstream;
      proxy_set_header Host $host:80;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
  }
}
stream {
  map $ssl_preread_server_name $upstream {
    example.com 1101;
    www.example.com 1101;
  }
  upstream 1101 {
    server 127.0.0.1:1101;
  }
  server {
    listen 443;
    proxy_pass $upstream;
    ssl_preread on;
  }
}
```

### The Goal

*Use the reverse proxy function to stream traffic to a background service. I do NOT want the traffic decrypted as it transits the reverse proxy. The certificates for the service reside on the upstream server; not the reverse proxy.*

I will not list all the articles I have read trying to figure this out, but something along this line is what I am aiming for...

This is ***NOT*** a valid code block.

```
stream {
  ## ssl_preread_server_name does not work for for non-ssl traffic
  map $ssl_preread_server_name $upstream { 
    example.com 
      ## If unencrypted HTTP on port 80, route to upstream 1100
      if ( unecrypted on port 80 ) { 1100;}
      ## If encrypted HTTPS on port 443, route to upstream 1101
      if ( encrypted on port 443 ) { 1101;}
      ## If encrypted SSH on port 22, route to upstream 1102
      if ( encrypted on port 22 ) { 1102;}
    somethingelse.com 
      ## If unencrypted HTTP on port 80, route to upstream 1200
      if ( unecrypted on port 80 ) { 1200;}
      ## If encrypted HTTPS on port 443, route to upstream 1201
      if ( encrypted on port 443 ) { 1201;}
      ## If encrypted SSH on port 22, route to upstream 1202
      if ( encrypted on port 22 ) { 1202;}
  }
  upstream 1100 {
    server 127.0.0.1:1100;
  }
  upstream 1101 {
    server 127.0.0.1:1101;
  }
  upstream 1102 {
    server 127.0.0.1:1102;
  }
  upstream 1200 {
    server 127.0.0.1:1200;
  }
  upstream 1201 {
    server 127.0.0.1:1201;
  }
  upstream 1202 {
    server 127.0.0.1:1202;
  }
  server {
    listen 80;
    ## Should route to 1100 or 1200 depending on domain
    proxy_pass $upstream;
  }
  server {
    listen 443;
    ## Should route to 1101 or 1201 depending on domain
    proxy_pass $upstream;
    ssl_preread on;
  }
  server {
    listen 22;
    ## Should route to 1102 or 1202 depending on domain
    proxy_pass $upstream;
  }
}
```

There are two problems with that...

1. It obviously does not work.
2. [If is evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) - I really want to stay away from `if`

If there is a better way to tackle this problem, I am open to it.

Comment: See if this <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34741571/nginx-tcp-forwarding-based-on-hostname/40135151#40135151> helps. I have a similar sort of requirement.