# Use NGINX Proxy (manager) to forward HTTPS and HTTP Traffic based on the hostname

Tags: nginx, ssl, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have the following setup here:

public IP -> nginx -> Backend A, Backend B etc...

I would like to forward the HTTPS and HTTP traffic for certain domains to Backend A without terminating SSL on nginx.

The reason is, because Backend A should be able to request SSL certificates using lets encrypt by itself. Nginx should therefore forward all the traffic based on the hostname to Backend A.

My idea is:
Case 1: *.app.domain.tld (without SSL termination on nginx) -> Backend A
Case 2: sample.domain.tld (with SSL termination on nginx) -> Backend B

Case 2 is the standard one. This works out of the box.

For Case 1 i need your help.

i found this information: [Nginx TCP forwarding based on hostname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34741571/nginx-tcp-forwarding-based-on-hostname)

This is 7 years old therefore i think it should definiteley be possible thesedays.
I am using the nginx proxy manager tool for configuring nginx. Do you know, whether i can set the neccessary setting within the UI?

The Streams section unfortunateley only allows me to forward all traffic regardles of the hostname to one target:

[image]

I also tried it using the regular proxy settings window (of course with a valid backendip):

[image]

The result is this:

[image]

Thanks for your help